# pseudo-compact space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, topological-groups

When $C^* (X) = C(X)$, $X$ is said to be  pseudocompact.   Every compact space is pseudocompact.

**my questions:**

> 1: IS $X$    pseudo-compact  if only if $f[X] $ is compact for $f$ in
>   $C^{*}(X)$?

$f[X] = \{ fx : x \in X \} $

**We know that a  Hausdorff space  is countably compact if only if every infinite set has a limit point.**

> 2:Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space.   If, of any two disjoint closed sets, at least one is compact, or even countably compact, **is $X$  countably compact?**

Answer (score 0):

Fact: If $X$ is pseudocompact, and $f: X \to Y$ is continuous then $f[X]$ is pseudocompact. The proof is immediate.

Fact 2: for metric spaces, pseudocompactness is equivalent to compactness.

These facts solve your first question.

As to the second: if $X$ is not countably compact (and $T_2$), $X$ has a countable closed and discrete set $A$. Split $A$ into two such sets. Then neither is (countably ) compact. This settles 2.